# Redirect to third party webiste on html submit and reset html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have one html page in which I am providing one registration form for user like this:

[image]

when user clicks on the submit button I want the user to redirect to https://domainname.com with the form variables as query parameters and then reset the form in html file.

But I can only redirect the user to some other site but can not reset the form.

Here is my code:

```
     <section class="green-bg">
            <div class="container wide">
                <div class="row joinnow-div" id="joinnow">
                <!-- Form styles-->
                        <h3>Join us today</h3>
                        <form action="https://domainname.com/" target="_blank" id="joinnow-form">
                            <label for="businessname">Your business's name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="businessname" name="businessname" placeholder="Business Name" required>

                            <label for="phonenumber">Contact number</label>
                            <input type="tel" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="eg. 07700100100" required>

                            <label for="address">Your business's street address</label>
                            <textarea type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="eg. 123 Business street" required></textarea>

                            <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Eg. yourmail@email.com" required>

                            <a href="https://domainname.com/" target="_blank" >Already registered?</h3><br/><br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">                            
                        </form>
                <!-- -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

when I click the submit button it redirect the user to `https://domainname.com?businessname=&phonenumber=&email=&address=` which is ok but I want to reset the form after redirecting.

Any Idea how can I attempt this?

Comment: `<form onsubmit="this.reset()"></form>`

Comment: but this resets the form before redirecting to https://domainname.com which passes empty query parameters.
Please help

Comment: That makes sense. Let me check probably need to add minor `timeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this works:

```
<form action="" target="_blank" onsubmit=" setTimeout(() => this.reset())">
    <input name="hello">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```